# How to solve the following nonlinear O.D.E. analytically?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following nonlinear O.D.E.

$$\frac{\Bbb d^2\phi(z)}{\Bbb dz^2}=2k_1\sinh(\phi(z))-k_2,$$

where $k_1$ and $k_2$ are constants, and I’m not sure of how to solve it.

I know that if $k_2=0$ then I can multiply both sides by $\frac{\Bbb d\phi(z)}{\Bbb dz}$, leading to

$$\frac{1}{2}\frac{\Bbb d}{\Bbb dz}\left(\frac{\Bbb d\phi(z)}{\Bbb dz}\right)^2=2k_1\sinh(\phi(z))\frac{\Bbb d\phi(z)}{\Bbb dz},$$

and integrating once,

$$\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\Bbb d\phi(z)}{\Bbb dz}\right)^2-2k_1\cosh(\phi(z))=c,$$ where $c$ is a constant related to the boundary conditions of the equation.

Then, I define $\psi=\sqrt{4k_1\cosh(\phi)+2c}$ and solve $\frac{\Bbb dz}{\Bbb d\phi}=\frac{1}{\psi}$.

I know that $\frac{\Bbb dz}{\Bbb d\psi}=\frac{\Bbb dz}{\Bbb d\phi}\frac{\Bbb d\phi}{\Bbb d\psi}$, the first term is $1/\psi$ and the other one is $\psi/2k_1\sinh(\phi)$, and as $\sinh(\phi)=\sqrt{\left(\frac{\psi^2-2c}{4k_1}\right)^2-1}$, I get that

$$\frac{\Bbb dz}{\Bbb d\psi}=\frac{1}{2k_1\sqrt{\left(\frac{\psi^2-2c}{4k_1}\right)^2-1}}.$$

I can probably integrate, but I’m not that sure how to proceed here…

For $k_2\neq 0$, once I multiply both sides by $\Bbb d\phi/\Bbb dz$ and integrate, I get $k_2\phi$.

Then, I define $\psi=\sqrt{4k_1\cosh(\phi)+2c+2k_2\phi}$ and $\frac{\Bbb dz}{\Bbb d\psi}=\frac{1}{2k_1\sinh(\psi)+2k_2}$. Now, $\sinh(\phi(z))=\sqrt{\left(\frac{\psi^2-2k_2\phi-2c}{4k_1}\right)^2-1}$ and therefore I get
$$\frac{\Bbb dz}{\Bbb d\psi}=\frac{1}{2k_1\sqrt{\left(\frac{\psi^2-2c-2k_2\phi}{4k_1}\right)^2-1}+2k_2}.$$

And again I’m stuck. I don’t like having $\phi$ down there…
Any suggestions are welcome!

In case it is of any use: this is related to the Poisson-Boltzmann equation.

Comment: In case it is of any use: this is related to the Poisson-Boltzmann equation

Answer (score 1):

*Similar to your approach but probably faster.*

Switching variables, the equation is
$$-\frac{z''}{(z')^3}=2k_{1}\sinh(\phi)-k_{2}$$ Reduce the order $p=z'$ and let $p=\frac 1 {\sqrt q}$, this leads to
$$q'=4 k_1\sinh(\phi)-2k_{2}$$ that is to say
$$q=4 k_1\cosh(\phi)-2k_{2} \phi+k_3$$ that is to say
$$p=\pm \frac 1 {\sqrt{4 k_1\cosh(\phi)-2k_{2} \phi+k_3}}$$ and I am afraid that,now, we face a nightmare **except** if $k_2=0$. In such a case, we should face some elliptic integral.

The solution would be
$$z=c_2 \pm \sqrt{\frac{2}{c_1-2 k_1}}\,\, F\left(\frac{i \phi }{2}|\frac{4 k_1}{2
   k_1-c_1}\right)$$  where appears the elliptic integral of the first kind.